# How to make a Hoverover Block inline

Tags: html, css

I just started understanding HTML and doing a bit of Programming so i would appreciate a simple reply! Im trying to create a test website with a 5x5 table of Block which which scale up once hovering over my current code is. I dont find any way of combing it with https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp but havent find a way yet!  :)

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

div:hover {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Georgia;">Lorem ipsum</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. You want multiple divs? Either `display: inline-block;` or look into flexbox or css grid.

Comment: Where in my code can i add the display: inline-block;? My goal is a 5x5 grid of these div blocks which when you hover they expand as a cool animation. I was able to do this with 1 block but i dont know how to inline them

Comment: Check out [CSS Rule: Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)

Comment: So your actual question is how do I make a grid layout that is 5 x 5.

Answer (score 0):

Use scale transform rather than `width` which makes it into a block. Also set style of the element to be `display: inline-block` which allows you to enjoy both of the worlds.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: gray;
  transition: 0.5s all;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p style="text-align: center;">hello <span style="font-family: Georgia;">Lorem ipsum</span> world</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer-**

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  transition: all 0.7s ;
}

div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5) `//Use scale trnsform`
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
}
<div>
  <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Georgia;">Lorem ipsum</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use transform scale(1.3) if you have 100px height & 100px width, and you want it to be 130px after hover.

I guess this is what you mean :

**CSS:**

```
    .flex-grid{
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    .flex-row{
        display: flex;
    }

    .flex-col{
        margin: 1rem;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: gray;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        font-family: Georgia;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .flex-col:hover{
        transform: scale(1.3);

    }
```

```
<div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
        <div class="flex-col"><p><span>Lorem ipsum</span></p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**(The final result, scales from the center of the box, on hover) :**

**[image: HTML :]**

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should remove the transition because you have already defined width and height. Also you should try to add an id or class to the div and call it with the id or the class. In that way you will specify to which div you want to add the CSS rules. Also you can change the font-size if you want to.

```
.text {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: gray;
}

.text:hover {
 width: 130px;
 height: 130px;
 background:gray;
 }

<div class="text">
  <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: 
   Georgia;">Lorem ipsum</span></p>
</div>
```